# make mysql answer how many names are in table

Tags: mysql

[image: simple table]

Let's assume we have this very simple 'test' table.

There is: 5 bob, 2 adam, 1 alex.

Is there anyway I can make MySQL answer something like this:

```
name | count
bob  | 5
adam | 2
alex | 1
```

Without using php? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(1) AS count
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I vote Paolo. All on one line, how sweet it is. Just wanted to throw up sqlfiddle to show it in action.

Comment: Thank's guys ! I vote all of you! Btw, What's the difference between COUNT(1) and COUNT(*) ?

Comment: @Reacen no difference. MySQL automatically converts COUNT(*) to COUNT(1). But on other databases, (1) may be faster sometimes, so I prefer this way of writing it for portability purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) as total
FROM test
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Here's a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a9f2/3

Comment: Thank's for the sqlfiddle link ! very handy too